# BAPI gets called multiple times in Android SUP application Async Task

Tags: android, mobile, bapi, sup

I am new to SUP Mobility .

I have a MBO created for Image uploading in SUP Sybase and I call it via  thread in android code inside a Async task call.

But , it so happens that the BAPI is getting called multiple times at backend .

Kindly suggest .